# Cypher count() returns values for non-existing nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

As title says.

```
MATCH (n:Person) RETURN count(n)
```

returns

```
│"count(n)"│

│1481      │
```

But

```
MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n
```

returns

```
(no changes, no records)
```

I used the same query for multiple times without error, and this happened just now for no apparent reason.
This is driving me nuts - I don't think I've ever seen this problem.

I'm using neo4j 3.3.4.

p.s. I've just moved the retention log files to the other drive to make some free spaces - could this be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the transaction log files, then that's likely the case. You should not ever touch the transaction logs yourself, you may have induced corruption in your graph.

Here's the [documentation on transaction logs](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/transaction-logs/), including how to set your configuration properties to handle rotation and retention of the logs.

You may want to use the [consistency checker](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/consistency-checker/) to confirm the consistency of the database.

Comment: Thought that'd be the cause but that page didn't help at all -
dbms.tx_log.rotation.retention_policy=false
didn't stop neo4j from making more of those transaction log files, and checkpoint was set to be set every 900 seconds but transaction logs over a whole week didn't have any checkpoint; hence I cannot remove any of the recent transaction log files (otherwise neo4j will say there aren't any checkpoint and refuses to open itself)

Comment: I recovered the transaction logs but to no avail - the bug persists.

Comment: Unfortunately, "recovering" the logs is unlikely to help, since those stale logs would likely no longer be in sync with the current logs or the state of the DB.